# Best file system for USB stick for backup purposes

Tags: backup, time-machine, usb, hfs+

I bought a 128GB stick to back up my MacBook Air (Time Machine). This way I don't need to re-format my external HDD I use for backing up files from my Windows machine. Since I won't be using the stick with my Windows machine I thought I might format it with a "better" file system than exFat. Would you recommend formatting it to HFS+?

Comment: You could have partitioned your old HDD and used it for two different file systems at the same time. You could install a HFS+ driver on your Windows machine to access the HFS+ partition from there too. HFS+ is *required* for TM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Apple KB : [Backup disks you can use with Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/HT202784)

> **Formatting a backup disk for use with Time Machine**
>
> The most common format for a Time Machine backup disk is Mac OS Extended (Journaled) format.
>
> Time Machine also supports Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled), Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled, Encrypted), and Xsan formats.
>   If your disk uses the Master Boot Record (MBR) partition type, some partitions might not be available for use with Time Machine.

In short, use a Journaled HFS+ partition on a GUID[GPT] formatted disk for best results.

Answer (score 3):

### For macOS Big Sur 11.0 and newer

Since macOS Big Sur, the best file systems to use for Time Machine backups are **APFS** and **APFS Encrypted**, as mentioned in the [macOS User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/types-of-disks-you-can-use-with-time-machine-mh15139/11.0/mac/11.0):

> APFS or APFS Encrypted disks are the preferred format for a Time Machine backup disk. If you select a new backup disk that’s not already formatted as an APFS disk, you get the option to erase and reformat it. If the disk is a Mac OS Extended format disk that contains an existing Time Machine backup, you aren’t asked to erase and reformat the disk.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use your USB stick for multiple operating systems (like Windows, Mac, Linux), then you should format your USB stick in the following way:

- If your USB is <= 4 GB, then format with FAT
- If your USB is <= 32 GB, then format with FAT32
- If your USB is <= 64 GB, then format with exFAT

NTFS and APFS/HFS are only for Windows and macOS respectively, don't use this if you want to use it on multiple operating systems.

This mostly worked for me.

Comment: But Time Machine only works on HFS and APFS so you can't use a FAT based format